# Multiple routers DHCP and firewall in the same LAN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, modem

I have a low quality modem/router (comtrend) and a slightly better router (tp-link) that I want to use to extend the wifi range. They are connected via ethernet.

My question is, can I safely delegate DHCP and firewall to the second router and use the cheap one only as modem and access point? If so, is it a good idea or am I missing something? Is it safe?

Actual config:

> (MODEM/ROUTER) ===== (ROUTER)
>
> internet+dhcp+firewall ------ access point

Proposed config:

> (MODEM/ROUTER) ===== (ROUTER)
>
> internet+access point ------ dhcp+firewall

Both routers have PCs connected and wifi

Thanks

Comment: DHCP yes, Firewall no, unless your entire LAN is on the LAN side of router 2, which doesn't sound like what you are proposing. A DHCP server can be anywhere on your LAN, but the firewall must be on a gateway (in this case your modem/router).

Comment: Thank you @FrankThomas ! So port forwarding must be handled in the gateway router as well?

Comment: yes. those are both gateway functions, because traffic has to pass through them for the function to be useful.

Comment: Note that the DHCP server must be sufficiently _configurable_ – you need to tell it to advertise the correct "default gateway" IP address. (By default it'll put its own address there, and many cheap routers don't allow changing that.)

Comment: Also, if the DHCP server _does_ advertise _its own_ IP address, then you'll end up with data passing through _two_ gateways (both routers in a row), which is technically kinda valid and even allows _either_ to act as a firewall... but a very easily bypassable firewall at that. Not to mention the overhead it incurs.